# PHP/MySQL - Geting a row from a DB

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me with my script? It's supposed to read the user's session's `member_id`, find the corresponding row and echo it out. But when it runs, it outputs nothing.

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//Make sure user is logged in
require_once('auth.php');

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Connect to DB
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
die("Unable to select database");
}

//Create Querys
$query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "' "; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Gather the whole row into an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo $row;     
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop a `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` immediately after the mysql_query line, and see if you've any results returned from the query - I suspect you'll find you haven't, in which case the SESS_MEMBER_ID is not present in the stats table.

Comment: Opps, I figured it out. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_*()` functions
2. `$row` is an array so echoing it is pointless: [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), [`var_dump()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)
3. Make sure that SQL query returns anything. Maybe `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` has got some unexpected value?
4. Do the basic debugging whenever something goes wrong - dump everything:

   ```
   var_dump($query); 
   var_dump($result);
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   ```

   Or even better: use a real debugger.
5. Make sure that every possible error is displayed - PHP is a very strange language that accepts tones of errors and still can work:

   ```
   error_reporting(-1);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
   ```

btw: What's the point of `SESS_` prefix for session variables?